# How to perform type checking with the typing Python module?

Tags: python, typing

I am reading the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module code and also looking into [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) to understand how it does type checking. Unfortunately for me, `mypy` builds a very smart tree with typed expressions that I still don't understand, and it's all based on static analysis.

I would like to implement a type check system that is dynamic (no static analysis) in Python. Assuming the function that performs type checks is called `check_type`, I want to accomplish the following:

```
>>> import typing
>>>
>>> check_type(1, int)
True
>>> check_type(1, float)
False
>>> check_type([1], typing.List[int])
True
>>> check_type([1], typing.List[float])
False
>>> check_type([1], typing.List[typing.Any])
True
>>> check_type((1,), typing.Tuple[int])
True
```

I thought about recreating the object type from its value, such as:

```
>>> get_type([1])
typing.List<~T>[int]
```

But this doesn't work with `issubclass`:

```
>>> issubclass(typing.List[int], typing.List[typing.Any])
False
```

I don't see a simple way to check types in Python without assuming a lot of things about [the internals of the `typing` stdlib module](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/lib-typing/2.7/typing.py) (e.g., accessing `__args__` or `__tuple_params__`).

How can I properly implement a `check_type` function that work for the cases previously listed? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Isn't this just `isinstance`?

Comment: No, @user2357112. `isinstance` doesn't check the type completely. For example: `isinstance(['string'], typing.List[int]) is True` when that's not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: First of all: you have to specify your rules for `check_type`. Once you do that you just have to move them from paper to a proper implementation. It seems that you are not sure how `check_type` should work to begin with. What does `I would like to implement a type check system that is dynamic (no static analysis) in Python.` even mean? There is no static analysis in Python.

Comment: @freakish: Check out [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), a static type analysis tool for Python and one of the big drivers behind type hints.

Comment: Besides maybe what you are trying to achieve is wrong? Python was never meant to do any type checking,.

Comment: Not really an answer but the pythonic way to check types is to use a `try/except` statement and treat the value you want to test as the value you expect and if a `TypeError` exception is raised do something else or just pass

Comment: @freakish: [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) (accepted). Although it doesn't quite apply to Python 2.7.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible for all inputs. Generally you would need a way to check the type of "contained objects" in a container and I don't think that for user defined types you can get that information (reliable - of course if \_\_iter\_\_ is implemented and the "contained type" only applies to objects that get returned by \_\_iter\_\_ you can check that). That said it should be possible for builtins/known classes.

Comment: @kennytm Yes, yes, I know all about those abominations.

Comment: Besides there's a general question. If I add dynamically an attribute to an object is it still of the same type? What about dynamic properties of classes? Can an object change type (a list which is `[1]` first and then `['foo']`)? It sure looks like it. Besides if you say that `[1]` is of type `List[int]` then it means that you are looking at an object that is attached to the list.

Comment: So strictly speaking you are not interested in the type but more in a current structure of an object (which can change in time). This can be probably done by some tricky recursion (perhaps serialization?) but I would not go down that road. Mostly because I don't see benefits of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get the very limited functionality that works correctly for the simple examples provided in your question:

```
import mypy.api

def check_type(value, typ):
    program_text = 'from typing import *; v: {} = {}'.format(typ, repr(value))
    normal_report, error_report, exit_code = mypy.api.run(['-c', program_text])
    return exit_code == 0

int_ = 1
str_ = 'a'
list_str_ = ['a']
list_int_ = [1]
tuple_int_ = (1,)

assert check_type(int_, 'int')
assert not check_type(str_, 'int')
assert check_type(list_int_, 'List[int]')
assert not check_type(list_str_, 'List[int]')
assert check_type(list_int_, 'List[Any]')
assert check_type(tuple_int_, 'Tuple[int]')
```

You can even do some more advanced stuff (for example, refer to the types that correspond to classes you defined in your program) by extending this code a bit, so that mypy gets to parse your entire source code as opposed to just the current line.

Alternatively, you might want to look at [enforce](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce) or [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard).