# Making python typing subscripted generics (Instance) checkable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'd love to be able to reuse `typing` a lot more, namely for type checking, and preferably in a way that's consistent with the usual way to check if something is of the type of...

(My) ideal would be to be able to do something like:

```py
from typing import Union, Iterable, Any, Mapping

KeysType = checkable(Union[Iterable[str], Mapping[str, Any]])

assert isinstance(['foo', 'bar'], KeysType)
assert not isinstance([3, 'foo', 'bar'], KeysType)
assert isinstance({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, KeysType)
assert isinstance({0: 0, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, KeysType)
assert not isinstance(5, KeysType)
```

Of course, something is a bit off since I'm using `isinstance` to mean `has_interface_of` or `has_compatible_stucture`. When wish bothers me, I tell myself this:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
isinstance(dict(), Mapping)
```

Yet a `dict` is not an instance of a `Mapping`.

Still, even a custom `is_sorta_like_this_type` function instead of the `isinstance` function would do, if hooking into the behavior of `isinstance` is too much of scary aberration.

Similar questions [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171908/extracting-data-from-typing-types) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985671/how-to-check-whether-a-variable-is-an-instance-of-a-subscripted-generics-defined) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973820/how-to-perform-type-checking-with-the-typing-python-module) on stackoverflow, but none of the proposed answers are quite satisfactory to me -- though [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973820/how-to-perform-type-checking-with-the-typing-python-module), though hacky, is the closest I got.

Comment: I think you are taking `isinstance` too literally. Just because `type(dict()) != Mapping` does not mean an instance of `dict` is not an instance of `Mapping`.

Answer (score 0):

The `typing` module has a few useful functions. You can access the contents of a subscripted generic like `Union` or `Optional` using [`get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args). This also works for subscripted type aliases such as `List`, `Mapping`, etc.